# JS array to tree by path

Tags: javascript

this is my first post ever here. I'm trying to make tree from array of objects by path. I'm unable to get second file into the same folder, folders can be nested infinitely. I'm a bit desperate, this is bugging me for a while...

The array: https://textuploader.com/149ku

```
let result = [];
let level = { result };
notes.forEach(note => {
    const pathSplit = note.path.split('/');
    pathSplit.reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
        if (!r[name]) {
            if (i === pathSplit.length - 1) {
                r[name] = { result: [{name: note.title}] };
                r.result.push({ name, children: r[name].result });
            }
            else {
                r[name] = { result: [] };
                r.result.push({ name, children: r[name].result });
            }
        }
        else {
            // What's here?
        }

        return r[name];
    }, level)
});
```

This is how react render looks:

```
const treeItems = nodes => {
    if(nodes){
        return nodes.map((node, index) =>{
            return (
            <NoteTreeItem style={{paddingLeft: '8px'}} key={index} nodeId={(Math.random()).toString()} labelText={node.name} labelIcon={FolderIcon}>
                {Array.isArray(node.children[0].children) ? 
                node.children.map(child => treeItems([child])) :
                 <NoteTreeItem saveEditNoteHandle={saveEditNoteHandle} note={node.children[0]} key={Math.random()} nodeId={Math.random().toString()} 
                 labelText={node.children[0].name} labelIcon={DescriptionIcon} />}
            </NoteTreeItem>)
        });
    }
};
```

[Missing file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP6W8.png)

EDIT: React code is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

To write straightforward paths like: `Idk.neco.neco`, it can be for example:

```js
const root = {};
notes.forEach((note, i) => {
  const folders = note.path.split('/');
  folders.reduce((folder, folderName, i, arr) => {
    // use prefix/suffix char that cant be contained in path to prevent overwriting
    folder[folderName] = folder[folderName] || {_name: folderName, _children: []}
    if (i === (arr.length - 1)) {
      folder[folderName]._children.push(note);
    }
    return folder[folderName]
  }, root)
})

console.log(root.Idk.neco.neco)
```

```html
<script>
var notes =[
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-14T06:30:36.259Z",
      "_id": "5e6c7a0c8506272230e0ab64",
      "title": "Firewall",
      "desc": "1) Update\n2) Allow ports\n3) chmod shortcuts\n4) bash\n5) something\n6) something else",
      "tag": "Work",
      "path": "sysadmin/linux",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-14T06:31:56.999Z",
      "_id": "5e6c7a5c8506272230e0ab65",
      "title": "Garden work",
      "desc": "Help her with garden work and with cooking",
      "tag": "Life",
      "path": "Help/Mom",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-14T06:32:40.738Z",
      "_id": "5e6c7a888506272230e0ab66",
      "title": "Learn Stocks",
      "desc": "When to buy/sell and how to predict",
      "tag": "Business",
      "path": "Money/stocks",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-19T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-14T06:34:44.629Z",
      "_id": "5e6c7b048506272230e0ab69",
      "title": "Kombinatorika",
      "desc": "Permutace",
      "tag": "School",
      "path": "Math class/something/another subfolder/topic",
      "remindDate": "2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-14T06:34:58.273Z",
      "_id": "5e6c7b128506272230e0ab6a",
      "title": "Posloupnost",
      "desc": "Geometricka a neco",
      "tag": "Work",
      "path": "Math class/something/something/different subfolder/topic",
      "remindDate": "2020-04-16T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-14T06:37:34.568Z",
      "_id": "5e6c7bae8506272230e0ab6b",
      "title": "FTP server",
      "desc": "Allow group A and B to access FTP",
      "tag": "Work",
      "path": "sysadmin/windows",
      "remindDate": "2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-15T05:29:29.345Z",
      "_id": "5e6dbd398c496347ac5e1010",
      "title": "PC",
      "desc": "Run antivirus",
      "tag": "Life",
      "path": "Help/Dad",
      "remindDate": "2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-17T09:11:20.558Z",
      "_id": "5e70943831441216a49faae4",
      "title": "2021",
      "desc": "2021",
      "tag": "No category",
      "path": "No category",
      "remindDate": "2021-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-17T18:53:46.443Z",
      "_id": "5e711cba9f3edb19a41ca77a",
      "title": "17",
      "desc": "17",
      "tag": "No category",
      "path": "17",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-19T08:20:53.237Z",
      "_id": "5e732b65a059104a01e0c510",
      "title": "20",
      "desc": "20",
      "tag": "Life",
      "path": "20",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-19T19:02:28.373Z",
      "_id": "5e73c1c4129dc33e68995634",
      "title": "not 20",
      "desc": "not 20",
      "tag": "School",
      "path": "20",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-21T07:18:44.770Z",
      "_id": "5e75bfd4baa9fc431475ed7b",
      "title": "VIM",
      "desc": "learn vim/vi :D",
      "tag": "School",
      "path": "sysadmin/linux",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-03-25T07:31:24.943Z",
      "_id": "5e7b08cc3d441b1f263304ee",
      "title": "Sometging",
      "desc": "Ckntent\n\n\n",
      "tag": "Life",
      "path": "Idk/neco/neco",
      "remindDate": "2020-03-26T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "check": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-04-04T15:07:45.435Z",
      "_id": "5e88a2c134a35d05568ac15a",
      "title": "first file",
      "desc": "first file",
      "tag": "No category",
      "path": "twofiles/folder",
      "remindDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "check": false,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-04T15:07:58.312Z",
        "_id": "5e88a2ce34a35d05568ac15b",
        "title": "second file",
        "desc": "second file",
        "tag": "No category",
        "path": "twofiles/folder",
        "remindDate": "2020-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
];
</script>
```